# Logcat in android studio will not display any of my logs

Tags: android

I have been doing much programming with android studio recently but now it will not display any logs that I put in my code.  Logcat works but it only displays what I would guess are system logs.  My syntax seems to be correct and i have the right class imported but my logs will not show up.  I have restarted logcat, restarted adb, restarted android studio, and even did a completely fresh install of android studio.  It won't log on any device, not my phone, tablet, emulator, nothing.  There are no filters on my Logcat either.  I am completely stumped.  Here is an example of some super simple code that won't log.

```
package com.bobbydouglass.logcat;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void showLog(View view) {
        Log.v("", "Logged");
    }
}
```

Comment: when do you call this showLog?

Comment: What are you doing to call `showLog()`? Is that a button with an xml reference to the function?

Comment: Yes the xml reference to the showLog() works.  The app just has a simple button that calls showLog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        showLog();
    }

    public void showLog() {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Logged");
    }
}
```

- Set the filter for error (just to test)
- You can select your package name in the dropdown
- You can filter with a string
- Call show log in `onCreate()` and remove the `View` param

Comment: I have tried all levels of logging including changing the Log type in the code.  It still will not show up.

Comment: Thank you this worked.  I guess the problem was that I just needed a proper tag?

Comment: The tag is helpful for filtering since the device generates lots of logs